# External stylesheet per page

Tags: pages, css

I want to know if this is a good thing to do. I have many `conditional tags` for `Wordpress pages` and all of them are combined in 1 stylesheet, which is not bad, but I see that the front-page for example does not use 50% of the stylesheet. Is there any reason to use the whole stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach (one general css) will make your first-load times longer, but when you browse other pages, if the  css is cached, everything will be faster.

If you make your stylesheet smaller by splitting them up.. you might have a 'slightly faster' first-page load but every other page that uses another css will still be slower than using one generic css for all pages.

You can minify them if you want as what @JMa have said, you can use caching plugins or even a CDN like cloudflare if you want to make your site faster..

Here is a tool to check your page load times for free:

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ or http://www.webpagetest.org/

Answer (score 3):

To get a better performance it's often recommanded to use only one stylesheet simply because it's just 1 request to the server. This is what a minify plugin does, it combines stylesheets.